# Can I upload custom artwork to Forza 4?

Tags: xbox-360, forza-motorsport-4

I'm thinking about purchasing Forza 4 for Xbox.  I know I can "customize" my car's paint job in the game, but is it possible to upload my own images/decals to the game to put onto my car?  Say, something like a company logo or a picture of my dog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, there's no way [about to do it](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997653-forza-motorsport-4/60702022).

> You can't. All images you see are carefully constructed using various shapes and tools within the game.

Comment: My research has revealed as much.  Thanks for taking the time.